# Foundation: Nesting grids with different amount of total columns

Tags: sass, grid, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I'm using a basic `12 col` grid which works perfectly fine. This is my `_settings.scss`

```
$grid-row-width: $global-width;
$grid-column-count: 12;
$grid-column-gutter: (
        small: 20px,
        medium: 30px,
);
$grid-column-align-edge: true;
$grid-column-alias: 'columns';
$block-grid-max: 8;
```

And this my markup:

```
<div class="grid-container wrapper">
    <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">
        <div class="cell medium-12"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now as mentioned I'm happy with the `12 cols` and I want to keep it like this. Now for a specific element, I need to use a nested `24 col` grid, which would end up in smth. like the following markup:

```
<div class="grid-container wrapper">
    <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">
        <div class="cell medium-12">
            <div class="grid-container wrapper">
                <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">
                    <div class="cell medium-24"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you try `medium-12` instead of `medium-24`?

Comment: @GibinEalias yeah, but this wont work, since default is a `12 col` grid.

Comment: please do not use the `foundation` tag as this is for the OSX framework foundation and not Foundation Sites (which start with zurb-foundation) ;-)

Comment: See https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/xy-grid.html#grids, https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/xy-grid.html#cells and further down and the other mixins like https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/xy-grid.html#xy-grid-layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems not like it's solvable by simply using class names. But you are able to define the `col` width manually with `xy-cell-size()`

This is my updated `scss`:

```
.custom-medium-24 {
    width: xy-cell-size(24 of 24);

    @include breakpoint(small only) {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.custom-medium-14 {
    width: xy-cell-size(14 of 24);

    @include breakpoint(small only) {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Thanks for the hints in the comments!